# List vs Numpy array computing speed: for loops

Tags: python, list, numpy, performance, loops

I was wondering if appending to a list in python would be faster or slower than filling up an 'empty' numpy array. I know that numpy is written directly in C and therefore I expect it to be faster than build in functions in python. I wrote a code to see if this was indeed the case. What I found, however, is that a filling up a list is faster than a np array. I tested this code for larger n as to be able to neglect the effect of loading in the numpy library. Does anyone know why this is the case? Thanks!

code:

```
import time 
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

n = 10000000

t_np_0= time.perf_counter()
f = np.empty(n)
for i in range(n):
    f[i] = i

t_np_1 = time.perf_counter()
print("Time elapsed numpy: ", t_np_1 - t_np_0) 

t_list_0= time.perf_counter()
f = []
for i in range(n):
     f.append(i)

t_list_1 = time.perf_counter()
print("Time elapsed list: ", t_list_1 - t_list_0) 

speed = (t_np_1 - t_np_0)/(t_list_1 - t_list_0)
print("np is " + str((speed - 1)*100) + "% slower than list")
```

Comment: Did you show the times?  These comparisons are frequent on SO, and generally the two approaches time about the same

Answer (score 0):

First, you are using appending method for list and filling method for NumPy array.

However, you can also use filling method for list.

```
list = []
for i in range(n):
    list.append(i)
```

```
list = [None] * n
for i in range(n):
    list[i] = [i]
```

The fastest method would be like this:

```
list = list(range(n))
```

---

Second, using NumPy would be slower for the list (array) creation because it uses the external python library, NumPy.

However, if you want to use the list you created for any calculation, using NumPy may be faster.

```
import numpy as np

n = 1000000

data_np = np.arange(n)
data_list = list(range(n))

%timeit -n 10 -r 7 data_np / n
> 3.91 ms ± 392 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit -n 10 -r 7 [i / n for i in data_list]
> 81 ms ± 1.52 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```